# c# draw Images sequence?

Tags: c#, drawimage

I am doing multiple images draw with c# using DrawImage, how can I determine which image should be draw first? I have some images stacking with each other so I should determine which one to be drawn first , its like image on top of the another image, thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the question - of course DrawImage will draw images on top of one another, what is the desired effect are you looking for? You need to describe what criteria YOU the human being would use to choose the image ordering before we can help you turn that into code.

Comment: I think you'd better show us some code to specify how "some images stacking with each other" in your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking for how to draw images to overlap each other you can use [`Controls.SetChildIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex.aspx).